# Executable not able to find libstdc++ version

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I have different compilers installed on my machine. The default libstdc++.so is inside /usr/lib64.
I installed gcc 12.1 in "/home/myCompilers/gcc1210" folder and I am using my Clion to use this compiler. The executable is built correctly, but when I try to run this executable, it errors out:

/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by ./project_exe)

I have used `link_directories(/home/myCompilers/gcc1210/lib64)` command in CMake, to give the correct path of libstdc++.so, But the executable is not able to use it at run time.

What is the correct way to give runtime library search path in CMake.

Comment: `-Wl,-rpath=/home/myCompilers/gcc1210/lib64` I think? In linker flags.

Comment: That might work, but I am looking for proper CMake command

Comment: I would confirm that it works first, then think how to persuade CMake to emit this flag.

Comment: Yes it works, I am using this... but it is old style to provide link flags in this way. I want not to use this but something like add_runtime_library_path() command, which I am looking for.

Comment: Then [`CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH.html)?

Comment: Let me try this...

Comment: `link_directories(/home` is always a mistake... you need to write a proper toolchain file and not call `link_directories` at all.

Comment: It is probably easier and safer to statically link libstdc++ and libgcc_s. Much easier to copy the resulting executable between user accounts and machines, and much easier to upgrade to a newer gcc without breaking your existing programs. Note, do not statically link libc.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use [recommended way](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling) for setting `RPATH`:

```
# use, i.e. do not skip the full RPATH for the build tree
set(CMAKE_SKIP_BUILD_RPATH FALSE)

# when building, do not use the install RPATH already
# (but later on when installing)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH FALSE)

# the RPATH to be used when installing
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "")

# do not add the automatically determined parts of the RPATH
# which point to directories outside the build tree to the install RPATH
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with libstdc++
System provided gcc - /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.32

Latest gcc I built /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.31.
I relinked to the system .32 library. Everything works but
this not something I normally do. It will do for now.